# Java concurrent access to field, trick to not use volatile

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, memory-model, java-memory-model

Preface: I'm know that in most cases using a volatile field won't yield any measurable performance penalty, but this question is more theoretical and targeted towards a design with an extremly high corrency support.

I've got a field that is a `List<Something>` which is filled after constrution. To save some performance I would like to convert the List into a read only Map. Doing so at any point requires at least a volatile Map field so make changes visible for all threads.

I was thinking of doing the following:

```
Map map;

public void get(Object key){
    if(map==null){
        Map temp = new Map();
        for(Object value : super.getList()){
            temp.put(value.getKey(),value);
        }
        map = temp;
    }
     return map.get(key);
}
```

This could cause multiple threads to generate the map even if they enter the get block in a serialized way. This would be no big issue, if threads work on different identical instances of the map. What worries me more is:

Is it possible that one thread assigns the new temp map to the map field, and then a second thread sees that `map!=null` and therefore accesses the map field without generating a new one, but to my suprise finds that the map is empty, because the put operations where not yet pushed to some shared memory area?

**Answers to comments:**

- The threads only modify the temporary map after that it is read only.
- I must convert a List to a Map because of some speical JAXB setup which doesn't make it feasable to have a Map to begin with.

Comment: 'volatile' may have some cost especially in multiprocessor environments.  It may require memory barriers / flushing to ensure other threads see changes.

Comment: Can you explain how / when threads modify what list / map and why you want to copy a list into a map?

Comment: I don't see any problem (other that your code won't compile, no return type)

Comment: @stefan bachert is it really impossible that only some of the put operations are visible to other threads? I though it would be pure change which parts get flushed to shared memory. Making it possible that only half of the map is seen from the other thread.

Comment: You can't modify a map that is read only - and if you want to have the modification results of each thread visible for the other threads than you have to do some synchronized write to the list / map. - Your `get()` method needs synchronization because indeed thread A can see `map==null` and enter the `if` while thread B kicks in and still sees `map==null` and enter the `if` as well.

Comment: You have over 30 questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that one thread assigns the new temp map to the map field, and then a second thread sees that `map!=null` and therefore accesses the map field without generating a new one, but to my suprise finds that the map is empty, because the put operations where not yet pushed to some shared memory area?

Yes, this is absolutely possible; for example, an optimizing compiler could actually completely get rid of the local `temp` variable, and just use the `map` field the whole time, provided it restored `map` to `null` in the case of an exception.

Similarly, a thread could also see a non-null, non-empty `map` that is nonetheless not fully populated. And unless your `Map` class is carefully designed to allow simultaneous reads and writes (or uses `synchronized` to avoid the issue), you could also get bizarre behavior if one thread is calling its `get` method while another is calling its `put`.

Comment: This is how careful you need to be: http://mailinator.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Comment: @biziclop Interesting, I have seen that happen a couple of times, its good to see an explanation.

Comment: @biziclop: That *is* interesting, but its relevance to the OP's code is subtle. That particular race condition can only happen if two different threads call `put` on the same map at the same time, which isn't supposed to be possible in the OP's code. (However, it *can* happen in the OP's code, if the compiler eliminates the `temp` variable, and if two threads see `map == null` so both set `map` to a new map and start adding elements.)

Comment: @ruakh Exactly. But I also linked to the article for the more general point it makes: once you give up on correct synchronisation, you may not always get the data corruption you were bargaining for.

Comment: The article is interessing but it doesn't really talk about what could happen if multiple processors join the race, making memory flushes more interessing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create your Map in the ctor and declare it final?  Provided you don't leak the map so others can modify it, that should suffice to make your get() safely sharable by multiple threads.

Comment: I could only make it final when using some ugly delegation pattern and passing the List in through the constructor, which I don't want to do for these kind of classes. The List is generated by JAXB and I want to generate a map in a second step in a class inheriting from the base class which holds the list.

Comment: I believe creating your map in the ctor and marking it final is the only thing you can do to safely avoid sync.  How about using another class to create the list from JAXB and then pass it our orig class's ctor?

Comment: Yeah that would work, but my code would really bloat and the automatic bean generation would have missed its point. I think I will go for some volatile field for the root object. Any other thread accessing any object somehow linked to the root will be then forced to refresh every shared object.

Answer (score 0):

When you really in doubt whether an other thread could read an "half completed" map 
(I don't think so, but never say never ;-), you may try this.

map is null or complete

```
static class MyMap extends HashMap {
   MyMap (List pList) {
    for(Object value : pList){
        put(value.getKey(), value);
    }
   }
}

MyMap map;

public Object get(Object key){
    if(map==null){
        map = new MyMap (super.getList());
    }
    return map.get(key);
 }
```

Or does someone see a new introduced problem ?

Comment: That has the same problem: a different thread can see the assignment to `map` before the constructor has completed. See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, search the page for "Symantec".

Comment: Well, if you don't want to believe the facts, I certainly can't force you to. :-/

Comment: I found the paragraph which stated this. This means any "new" has to be synchronized otherwise you in danger to work with an incomplete object. So "new" is not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the visibility concerns previously mentioned, there is another problem with the original code, viz. it can throw a NullPointerException here:

```
return this.map.get(key)
```

Which is counter-intuitive, but that is what you can expect from incorrectly synchronized code.

Sample code to prevent this:

```
Map temp;
if ((temp = this.map) == null)
{

    temp = new ImmutableMap(getList());
    this.map = temp;
}
return temp.get(key);
```